# How to print CSV file input parameters in CSV file using bean shell processor in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm facing some issue while creating the script to print input test data+response for that data. I want to print input test data also, for example:

```
cards
98765432
98765432
```

Results CSV file:should be

```
Cards,Results
98765432,PASS
98765432,FAIL
```

How can I print like above? My code is

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

Result = "FAIL";
Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

if(Response.contains("fullCardNo"))
    Result = "PASS";
fullCardNo =vars.get("fullcards");
f = new FileOutputStream("F:\\Java_Applications\\apache-jmeter-3.1\\bin\\FullCardsResults.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);

this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println((${cards})+","+fullCardNo + "-" + Result);
f.close();
p.close();
```

By this above script,my results file showing empty, there is no data in that file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer where error in my script only,just i've changed and copy ,paste `fullCardNo =vars.get("fullcards");` in above the Result="FAIL" as below and below is the code works for me.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
cardsnumber =vars.get("cards");
Result = "FAIL";
Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
if(Response.contains("fullCardNo"))
    Result = "PASS";
fullCardNo =vars.get("fullcards");
f = new FileOutputStream("F:\\Java_Applications\\apache-jmeter-3.1\\bin\\FullCardsResults.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);

this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(cardsnumber+","+fullCardNo + "-" + Result);
f.close();
p.close();
```

Please follow above code then it is possible to print input variables also in results csv file as i asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible so I would suggest using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property instead

Given you set `sample_variables` property by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=cards,fullcards
```

or pass them to JMeter startup script via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=cards,fullcards -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
```

Your `result.csv` file will contain 2 extra columns where `${cards}` and `${fullcards}` values will be present. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) guide for more information on precisely tuning your JMeter instance(s) via properties.

---

If you **have to** do something which requires scripting make sure you are using the most performing option which is [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with Groovy language as of now.